# Dictionary of Words

Tags: database, csv, dictionary, symbian

I wanna develop a dictionary for Symbian(English-Persian) With Some Extra Features(That original one and anothers don't have).

But the big problem is database of words. There are some question I would be happy to be answered :

1- Is there any way to convert Freeware BGL(Babylon Glossaries) Dictionaries to Another readable formats(e.g. CSV or DB)??

2- Is there any database of words available(freeware or paid) to use???

Thanks For Answering.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it's hard to tell you exactly how but you can probably do it in the majority programming languages. I could tell you how in PHP if that would suit.
2. http://www.google.com

Comment: About #1 how???? Well, I'm a PHP Programmer but I haven't heard anything about that. Thanks in Advance.